# Jekyll site via Sinatra and Heroku - can't route to new posts

Tags: ruby, heroku, routes, sinatra, jekyll

I created a 'Hello, World' app using Sinatra and then pushed to Heroku and all worked.

I've since created a basic Jekyll blog, and am trying to access it via Heroku using the following routes:

```
get '/?' do
file.read("_site/index.html")
end

get '/.*.*' do
file.read("_site/#{params[:splat]}")
end

not_found do
file.read("_site/error/index.html")
end
```

The route to the index works fine [link to my site](http://intense-temple-9912.herokuapp.com/)
but as soon as I click to the first post it always fails.

I have tried so many variations of different routes for the `:splat` and `get`, just can't seem to get it to work? Any ideas?

Comment: What's the directory layout? Sorry, I have used Jekyll in the past I just don't keep it in my head. Also, try replacing any of the `file.read` statements with a string and see if you can see that. My first guess is that the path to the file isn't right.

Comment: @iain The directory layout is _layouts, _posts, _site, css all in the root folder, and it seems Jekyll puts new posts into the _site folder. if that makes sense, sorry I am very new to this. 
I'll try the changing file.read

Comment: Don't worry about being new to this, we've all been there! :) Which dir is Sinatra in? `root/app` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I find this out?
I require 'Sinatra' in my Gemfile?

Comment: Where's the file that defines the Sinatra routes? The ones you've given above.

Comment: It's in the root folder with the Gemfile, Procfile and _config.yml

Answer (score 0):

In the route that's failing, before the `file.read` statement, add `warn "splat = #{params[:splat]}"` and that will output the result to the terminal, and you can see what it's actually getting, e.g.

```
get '/.*.*' do
  warn "splat = #{params[:splat]}"
  file.read("_site/#{params[:splat]}")
end
```

You could also try using an absolute path to the files, though if you're getting the index page then it suggests it's not needed:

```
config do
  set :statics, File.expand_path(File.join(settings.root, "_site"))
end

get '/.*.*' do
  file.read( File.join settings.statics, params[:splat] )
end
```

Unless there's something else you were planning to use Sinatra's routes for, you could probably remove the Sinatra routes entirely and just make the "_site" folder the public_folder, and then [Sinatra will do the serving of the static files for you](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Static%20Files):

```
config do
  set :public_folder, File.expand_path(File.join(settings.root, "_site"))
end

# no more to do...
```